# Target and output in neural networks

Tags: time-series, neural-networks

In ANN the output squeezed using sigmoid function so the result is always between 1 and  -1.

How am I supposed to calculate the error when the target value  might be  a big number?

For example I'm using ANN to predict a time series, so I get output like 0.98 but the target is 34.5.

Comment: Welcome to CV! The phrasing of the current question seems quite unclear to me, I think it would benefit from more explanation about what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I want to predict a time series using neural network , the out put of the neural network is always between 0 and 1 and the target is big number like 45.4 so how can I calculate the error because it will always be a big number , is there any normalization I have to use with the time series data?

Comment: Rather than clarify in the comments, the best thing to do us edit your original question.

Comment: you rescale the target to between -1 and 1 (based on training data) and then use same scaling for predictions ie  test data.  Note that typically you would have a linear output neuron if you are doing regression (predicting an amount) rather than classification

Comment: @seanv507 do you suggest any type of normalization for this purpose knowing that the data I have is type of double and between 90 and 160

Comment: well typically you would rescale to mean zero variance 1. ( and often in time series prediction you use the previous value to predict the future value, so it makes sense to be consistent between input and output. [ with linear output neuron you don't need any rescaling]

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- have no activation function on your output layer (the "identity" activation function).
- scale your targets so that their range is spanned by the activation function of the output layer. For a typical sigmoid (logistic activation function), it would be between 0 and 1 (not -1 and 1 as you wrote).

Usually the second option is preferred because it is easier to initialize the weights.

Answer (score 0):

The sigmoid activation is good for outputs bounded between 0 and 1 such as probabilities for classification.

In case you don't need specific bounds you can use other non-linearities like ReLU(x) = max(0,x). In case you do know some bounds for the output you can use the sigmoid and then do a linear transformation.

*Warning*: I saw that you are trying to train a Neural Network for a time series. Note that if you're starting with Neural Networks you may want to start with a simple FeedForward network applied to some simple problem (sequences are usually handled with Recurrent Neural Nets which are harder to train).